# using jquery with a radio group to toggle parent <label> class attributes

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have searched.

The idea is that when a radio is selected its parent label changes class attribute from class="sample" to class="sample selected".

I have that.

The problem is when I choose one of its grouped "radio buddies" I need to:

1. Change the parent label of the currently selected radio back to "sample"
2. Change the now selected parent label to "sample selected"

> 

label class="sample">

```
<div class="col">    
 <div class="form-check d-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="event_type" class="form-check-input">
  Wedding Reception    
 </div>   
</div>
```

/label>

> ```
>  $('.sample').click(function() { $(this).addClass('selected'); });
> ```

Thank you

Comment: My second post.  I could not figure how to display <label>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either Method 1 or Method 2:

**Method 1: (From your post)**

```
$('.sample').click(function() {
   // Remove the existing 'selected' class. It will fulfill your first question
   $('.sample.selected').removeClass('selected'); 
  // Add the 'selected' class for newly clicked radio button's parent label element. It will fulfill your second question
   $(this).addClass('selected'); 
});
```

**Method 2:**

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
 // Remove the existing 'selected' class. It will fulfill your first question
  $('label.sample.selected').removeClass('selected');
 // Add the 'selected' class for newly clicked radio button's parent label element. It will fulfill your second question
  $(this).closest('label.sample').addClass('selected');
});
```

**Method 1 disadvantage:**

- If the already selected radio button clicked again. The method 1 do the functionalities (remove and add the selected class for the same label), even though the same radio button
- This will be avoided in Method 2. That is the method 2 only calls when the radio button changed.

Comment: Thank you for both answers!  Very thorough. Method 2 is definitely what I needed.